# Yii How to reset pageSize selected from drop down pagination on page refresh/reload

Tags: php, jquery, yii, pagination

I am working on yii TbExtendedGridView. I have written code for pagination from drop down and it is working fine but problem is on page reload or on change gridview I want to reset pageSize = default page size.
*Here is my code*,

**View Page code**

```
//pagination dropdown start
$pageSize=Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSizeUserList',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']);
//pagination dropdown end

$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'id' => 'UserList',
    'type' => 'striped',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
//pagination dropdown start
    'summaryText'=>'Rows per page '.
    CHtml::dropDownList('pageSizeUserList', $pageSize, Yii::app()->params['pageSizeOptions'],
            array('class'=>'change-pageSize',
                    'onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiGridView.update('UserList',{ data:{ pageSizeUserList: $(this).val() }})")).
                    ' Displaying {start}-{end} of {count} result(s)',
//pagination dropdown end
    'template' => "{summary}{items}{pager}",
    'ajaxVar' => 'ajax',
    'ajaxUpdate' => 'UserList',
    'columns'=>array(
      array(
            'name' => 'user_name',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode(($data->profile && $data->profile->name()) ? $data->profile->name() : $data->username), array("/user/user/view", "id" => $data->id))',
             'filter' => CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'candidate_name', ['class'=>'form-control small']),

        ),
)));
```

**Model page code**

```
'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSizeUserList',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),
        ),
```

**Controller page code**

```
//code for pagination start
public function actionAdmin($renderPartial = NULL) {
    if (isset($_GET['pageSizeUserList'])) {
        Yii::app()->user->setState('pageSizeUserList',(int)$_GET['pageSizeUserList']);
        unset($_GET['pageSizeUserList']);
    }
}
//code for pagination end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this in controller page code:

```
//code for pagination start
public function actionAdmin($renderPartial = NULL) {
     Yii::app()->user->setState('pageSizeUserList', Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']);    
     if (isset($_GET['pageSizeUserList'])) {
        Yii::app()->user->setState('pageSizeUserList',(int)$_GET['pageSizeUserList']);
    }
}
//code for pagination end
```

In the model paging code there's a semicolon before the last comma in line which should be removed

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, I tried with this and it was working for me but another problem is coming like if I will select 20 from drop down then I am getting 1 - 20 records. On the same page I have pager on bottom side of grid, now if I will click on NEXT then I am getting 11 - 20 records in place of this I should get 21 - 40 records

Comment: does it works when you change the dropdown to 20 and then refresh the page?

Comment: Sorry for let reply, yes it works for me but one more issue is there if i will use this code then for drop down and reset thing it is working fine. If I will select 20 from drop down and I have one more pager at bottom side of gridview so from bottom pager if i will click on next page then in grid view i am getting only 10 records. it should show me next 20 record but it is showing 11-20